# IsInArray Excel VBA ...out of range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to create an array by looping through a column in excel.  If an item is already in the array, then I want the code to skip to the next element of the column.

So for instance, when item1 is reached in the array for the second time, it would be skipped since it's already there

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub productKey()
    '
    ' productKey Macro
    Dim celltxt As String

    'each column element

    Dim ListofProducts() As String

    'declaration of array

    For i = 1 To 6

    celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)

    'grabs cell from column A

    If IsInArray(celltxt, ListofProducts) Then

         GoTo NextIteration

    Else

    ReDim Preserve ListofProducts(i)

    'expands the array while preserving existing elements

    ListofProducts(i) = celltxt

    'assigns elements that aren't in the array to the array

    End If

    productIndex = Application.Match(celltxt, ListofProducts, False)

    'gives the location of the cell in the array

    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = productIndex

    'then assigns it to column B

    NextIteration:

    Next i

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

I get the following: subscript out of range and then with debugging error is localized to the `isinarray` function.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251825.aspx). A dictionary object consists of pairs of data; a unique [key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ex01tte.aspx) and an associated [item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84k9x471.aspx).

The [Exists.Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251562.aspx) can test to see if a product already exists in the dictionary's unique keys.

```
Sub productKey()

    ' productKey Macro
    Dim a As Long, dPRODs As Object, arr As Variant

    Set dPRODs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'all of columns A & B into an array
        arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    'populate the dictionary
    For a = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not dPRODs.exists(arr(a, 1)) Then _
            dPRODs.Add Key:=arr(a, 1), Item:=arr(a, 2)
    Next a

    'get then out of the dictionary
    For Each arr In dPRODs.Keys
        Debug.Print arr & " - " & dPRODs.Item(arr)
    Next arr

    'transfer then to an array
    arr = dPRODs.Keys
    For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(a)
    Next a

    arr = dPRODs.Items
    For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(a)
    Next a

End Sub
```

Testing for Exists means that you will end up with the Item from the first occurrence of the Key. The code can be adjusted to accept the text from the last occurrence of the Key.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code was attempting to use the string array immediately upon declaration without assigning it any substance.

```
Sub productKey2()
    ' productKey Macro
    Dim celltxt As String, i As Long, productIndex As Variant

    'declaration and instantiation of array
    Dim ListofProducts() As String
    ReDim ListofProducts(i)  '<~~ give it something to work with

    For i = 1 To 6
        celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)

        'grabs cell from column A
        If IsInArray(celltxt, ListofProducts) Then
             GoTo NextIteration
        Else
            ReDim Preserve ListofProducts(i)

            'expands the array while preserving existing elements
            ListofProducts(i) = celltxt
            'assigns elements that aren't in the array to the array
        End If

        productIndex = Application.Match(celltxt, ListofProducts, False)

        'gives the location of the cell in the array
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = productIndex
        'then assigns it to column B

NextIteration:

    Next i

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```