# Adding values to a dynamic array and then printing to specified cell

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm searching a range in my sheet for certain values when either of these values is found I want to add the value from column A of that row to an array, only adding values that are not already present in the array. Once the range has been searched, I want to print the arrays to specified cells in the worksheet in 2 different columns.

Here's my code so far:

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Leave() As Variant, Join() As Variant
Dim LastCol As Integer, LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, Z As Integer
Dim J As Long, L As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Find Last Col
    LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Find last Row
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = LastRow - 1

    'ReDim Leave(1 To (LastRow - 1), LastCol)
    'ReDim Join(1 To (LastRow - 1), LastCol)

    For i = 5 To LastCol
        For Z = 4 To LastRow

            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Z, i).Value = "0" Then
                Leave(L) = Ws.Cells(Z, 1).Value

            ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Z, i).Value = "-2" Then
                Join(J) = Ws.Cells(Z, 1).Value

            End If
        Next Z
    Next i
    'Print array

End With
```

Thanks for any pointers/help in advance!

Comment: In a rush to give a detailed look to your code right now. But want to mention two things: 1) do not use Join as variable, is a reserved word; 2) for checking is value is already in array, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34754113/1726522) (the last function).

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? Right off the bat I can tell you you'll want to increment `L` and `J` when `Leave` and `Join` are updated (i.e. `Leave(L) = Ws.Cells(Z, 1).Value: L = L + 1`) or you'll just keep overwriting `Leave(0)` and `Join(0)` with each iteration.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using a dictionary or collection object instead of the array?

Comment: @J. Fox - increment throws an error (I did already try this.

Comment: @KacireeSoftware not to familar with dictionaries but is worth a try...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this procedure accomplishes what you are looking for. You will need to modify the range in which you are searching and the destination sheet information, but the meat of the procedure is here:

```
Sub abc_Dictionary()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim RangeToSearch As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim UniqueDict As Object

    Set oWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set RangeToSearch = oWS.Range("B1:B26") 'You can set this dynamically however you wish
    Set UniqueDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Now we search the range for the given values.
    For Each myCell In RangeToSearch
        If (myCell.Text = "0" Or myCell.Text = "-2") And Not UniqueDict.exists(oWS.Range("A" & myCell.Row).Text) Then
            UniqueDict.Add oWS.Range("A" & myCell.Row).Text, oWS.Range("A" & myCell.Row).Text
        End If
    Next

    'Now we have a dictionary object with the unique values of column a
    'So we just iterate and dump into Sheet2
    Dim d As Variant
    Dim Val As Variant
    Dim DestRow As Integer

    DestRow = 1 'This is the first row of data we will use on Sheet 2
    d = UniqueDict.Items
    For Each Val In d
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & DestRow).Value = Val
        DestRow = DestRow + 1
    Next



    Set UniqueDict = Nothing
    Set RangeToSearch = Nothing
    Set oWS = Nothing
End Sub
```